# Direct proof for the independence of $\operatorname{Tor}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

It is known that $\operatorname{Tor}$ is independent of the choice of the resolution.

More specifically, I am trying to do the [exercise 1 (c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaYZn.jpg) of Vick's homology theory.
The author gives the definition of free resolution right after proving the right exactness of tensor.

That means I need a direct proof of it without a lengthily reference of commutative algebra (which I poorly known).

(I copy that page in the book below for the definition and properties.)

It is helpful if anyone could also give me some hints about Exercise 1 (b) and 2.

[image: exercise 1(c)]

Comment: Homological algebra will be difficult for you if you don't have the basics in commutative algebra. I suggest that if you encounter commutative algebra concepts that you don't know, you learn more about them, instead of working around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 b), the exact sequence $0 \to A \to A \to 0$ is a free resolution of $A$, tensoring by $B$ and taking homology gives you $Tor(A,B)=0$.

For 2, use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring, that gives you an isomorphism of abelian groups $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B = B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$, for all abelian groups $A$ and $B$.

For 1 c), use the fact that if $0 \to C \to B \to A \to 0$ and $0 \to C' \to B' \to A \to 0$ are free resolutions, you can lift the identity $1_A:A \to A$ to a morphism $f:B \to B'$ such that the corresponding diagram commutes, and you may find a morphism $g: C \to C'$ that makes the new diagram commute. For there it is easy to find the required isomorphism.

I also recommend you to take a look at commutative algebra basics in order for you to understand better the homological algebra basics.